# Error while installing package

Tags: r, package, installation

I have the following error when I try to install a package :

```
>install.packages("ggplot2")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("utils")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
```

The thing is, until now, I never had problem installing packages, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MarcoSandri Put your comment as an answer and we can add this to the r faq. I want to give you the credit for this.